# XPath with selectsinglenode

Tags: c#, xpath

I have this XML input :

```
<BIEN>
    <AGENCE></AGENCE>
    <INFO_GENERALES></INFO_GENERALES>
    <VENTE></VENTE>
    <FORET></FORET>
    <LOCALISATION></LOCALISATION>
    <PROPRIETAIRE>
        <COMMENTAIRES>This is the comment i don't want to see</COMMENTAIRES>
    </PROPRIETAIRE>
    <COMMENTAIRES>
          <FR>This is the comment I want to see</FR>
    </COMMENTAIRES>
    </BIEN>
```

When I do :

```
XmlDocument docxml = new XmlDocument();
docxml.LoadXml("myfile.xml");
XmlNode root = docxml.DocumentElement;
XmlNode nodeCommentaires = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::COMMENTAIRES");
```

I have : This is the comment i don't want to see

But I want to see : This is the comment I want to see

What is the correct syntax that I have to use in selectSingleNode ?

Comment: you could just go /BIEN/COMMENTARIES/FR

Answer (score 1):

Use a child instead of a descendant:

```
"child:COMMENTAIRES"
```

or simply

```
"./COMMENTIRES"
```

or

```
"COMMENTAIRES"
```

They are all equivalent.